# Rotate child div perpendicular to parent div in 3D space

Tags: html, css, 3d, css-animations, css-transforms

```css
html {
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}
div div {
  top: 5rem;
  background-color: #444;
  transform-origin: top center;
}

.rotate_x {
  animation-name: rotate_x;
}
@keyframes rotate_x {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX( 0deg );
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX( 360deg );
  }
}

.rotate_y {
  animation-name: rotate_y;
}
@keyframes rotate_y {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY( 0deg );
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
  }
}
```

```html
<style>
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
  html, body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  body {
    perspective: 5rem;
  }
  div {
    position: relative;
    top: -1.5rem;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    background-color: #222;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
  }
</style>

<div class='rotate_y'>
  <div class='rotate_x'>
  </div>
</div>
```

The gray bottom `div` doesn't appear to be rotating out perpendicular to the black top `div` as intended. Instead the bottom gray div appears to shrink until it has a negative value and gets inverted. The desired result is for the bottom gray `div` to rotate up as if on a hinge; making a 'L' shape in 3D space
before it comes all the way up and flips around to do the same on the other side. As the parent div rotates 360 degrees.

How can I make the bottom `div` create an 'L' shape as it connects with it's parent div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `transform-style` and make the perspective a bit bigger:

```css
html {
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}
div div {
  top: 5rem;
  background-color: #444;
  transform-origin: top center;
}

.rotate_x {
  animation-name: rotate_x;
}
@keyframes rotate_x {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX( 0deg );
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX( 360deg );
  }
}

.rotate_y {
  animation-name: rotate_y;
  transform-style:preserve-3d; /* HERE */
}
@keyframes rotate_y {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY( 0deg );
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
  }
}
```

```html
<style>
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
  html, body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  body {
    perspective: 15rem;
  }
  div {
    position: relative;
    top: -1.5rem;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    background-color: #222;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
  }
</style>

<div class='rotate_y'>
  <div class='rotate_x'>
  </div>
</div>
```